# pass index to ng-class with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to increment class sequence with `ng-repeat`.
My requirement meets like

```
<div class="c1">image1</div>
<div class="c2">image2</div>
<div class="c3">image3</div>
......................
<div class="cN">imageN</div>
```

I tried to reduce this as

```
<div ng-class="{'c':{{imgNo}}}" ng-repeat="imgNo in imgNos">Image{{imgNo}}</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-class="{'c[$index]':isTrue}" ng-repeat="imgNo in imgNos">Image{{imgNo}}</div>
```

Please help me with the correct way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="c{{imgNo}}" ng-repeat="imgNo in ImgNos">Image{{imgNo}}</div>
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/mxafovoj/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
    $scope.List = [
        {Name : '1'},
        {Name : '2'},
        {Name : '3'},
        {Name : '4'},
        {Name : '5'}
    ];
    
   
});
```

```css
.c0{
  color:red;
  }

.c1{
  color:blue;
  }

.c2{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="category in List" ng-class="'c'+{{$index}}">
       {{category.Name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **don't need** to specify or use `$index` over here because you already have `imgNo` field and you use in div text, you can also **append** same name in class:

```
<div class="c{{imgNo}}" ng-repeat="imgNo in ImgNos">Image{{imgNo}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<div class="c{{imgNo}}" ng-repeat="imgNo in ImgNos">Image{{imgNo}}</div>
```